# On what class can I find the extension 'Where' for the type DbSet<TEntity> of EF Core 5.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, extension-methods

I am writing a method that generates some EFCore Linq code using Linq expressions for a specific filtering API. It will write some statements like:

```
dbContext.Student
.Where(s => s.Address.ZipCode == 10005)
.Intersect(dbContext.Student
                    .Where(s => s.FirstName == "John")
```

For that I need get the MethodInfo of the Where and of the Intersect methods.

I tried using GetMethod on the type but it returns null (not working on extension methods):

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Where",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
    null,
    CallingConventions.Any,
    new[] { typeof(IQueryable<Student>),
            typeof(Expression<Func<Student, bool>>)},
    null);
```

I also tried the following:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable)
       .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
       .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Where");
       // TO DO : taking the first of where Methods is bad.
       .First()
       .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(DbSet<Student>));
```

But I get a badArgument0 when used on DbSet.

Any clue of the class where I can find the right Where DbSet extension ?

Comment: You mean [`System.Linq.Queryable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-5.0) I guess, but why would you want the `MethodInfo` for that?

Comment: 'Where' is an example. I also need 'Intersect' and 'Union' and I need to compose the expression depending on some parameters. Sometimes 'Intersect' will be used, sometimes 'Union' will be used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `MethodInfo` here, you can create just call expression:

```cs
var queryable = dbContext.Student.AsQueryable();
var lambda = ...

var whereCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), 
     nameof(Queryable.Where), 
     new[] { typeof(Student) },
     queryable.Expression,
     lambda
  );

// and final
return queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<Student>(whereCall);
```